# Вопрос как сделать так чтобы скроллбар опустился на определенную высоту при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, css-animation

Мне нужно настроить скроллбар чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на кнопку его плавно прокручивало до того места которое я точно обозначил сам. написанный html,css,js. Прошу объясните как можно это реализовать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример. Обратите внимание, что я использовал **id** нужного элемента, чтобы до него докрутить.

```js
document.getElementById('scrollButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var targetElement = document.getElementById('targetElement');
  
  // Получаем координаты целевого элемента
  var targetPosition = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  
  // Вычисляем текущую позицию прокрутки
  var startPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  
  // Вычисляем расстояние, которое нужно прокрутить
  var distance = targetPosition - startPosition;
  
  // Задаем скорость прокрутки (в пикселях в секунду)
  var speed = 500; // пикселей в секунду
  
  // Вычисляем время, необходимое для прокрутки
  var time = Math.abs(distance / speed) * 1000; // миллисекунды
  
  // Плавно прокручиваем до целевой позиции
  window.scrollTo({
    top: targetPosition,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*Целевой элемент*/
#targetElement {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/*Кнопка для скрола*/
#scrollButton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
/*Элемент, чтобы занять место*/
.empty {
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<button id="scrollButton">Прокрутить</button>
<div class="empty">Просто, чтобы занять место</div>
<div id="targetElement">Целевой элемент</div>
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать это без JS?

Comment: @OliverPatterson обычно делаю это через JS. Буду не против, если расскажите, как без него сделать.

Comment: Банально вместо кнопки мы используем ссылку с "#ИД_БЛОКА".

Comment: @OliverPatterson ваша правда, совсем забыл про этот прием. Спасибо, что напомнили